# listenTo backbone event triggered from a particular element or view

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

Like in the events hash in a backbone view we specify events with a selector,
Example:-

```
  events: {
    "click .icon":          "open",
    "click .button.edit":   "openEditDialog",
    "click .button.delete": "destroy"
  }
```

How do you implement this with *listenTo*

```
this.listenTo('Events','mouseenter .icon',callback)
```

**PS**: I have multiple components( like buttons,checkboxes) and I have a UI which allows to bind listeners to those components in the DOM(allows component interaction). They have click,mouseenter etc default javascript events handled and triggered like for click and double-click something like this:-

```
Events.trigger('click',data);
```

or

```
Events.trigger('dblClick',data);
```

But I want to bind the listeners to specific components only, prohibiting the recipient from listening to mouseenter of all the existing dom components as mouseenter of any component will lead to Events.trigger('mouseenter',data).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing between DOM events from Backbone.Events -- they are not the same.

The events hash apply only to Backbone.View, and refers to DOM events that can be tied to event handler methods in your View.

`listenTo()` is a method in Backbone.Events that can apply to any object that mixes in Backbone.Events. The first parameter in your `listenTo()` method should be an object that has mixed in Backbone.Events.

Comment: So then, how should I bind event listeners (backbone Event listeners) limited to listening to a particular instance of a view only. I do have unique id  for each instance but i don't want to use a if loop at the recievers end to filter out the triggerers based on Id. Using if loop seems to be the incorrect or kind of a hardcoded way to go about.

Comment: Backbone Events can carry a payload.  So if your view instance has a viewId (for example), it could trigger an event with the event payload containing the viewId.  From the listener's point of view, the event handler will receive this payload as a parameter, and so will be able to check the value of the viewId before deciding to take appropriate action.